# numpy.where vs pandas.Series.map

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like to know over those two ways, which one should I use... or is there an even better way ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values' : [1, 27, 256, 312, ...]})
df['clip_values'] = df['values'].map(lambda x : 20 if x > 20 else x)
df['clip_values_v2'] = np.where(df['values'] > 20, 20, df['values'])
```

Thanks

Comment: Using `map` with a lambda function is going to be less performant by quite a large margin, but a better solution would use `clip`: `df['values'].clip(upper=20)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about better, here's one with [`clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) -

```
df['clip_values'] = df['values'].values.clip(max=20)
```

Timings on large data -

```
In [172]: df = pd.DataFrame({'values' : np.random.randint(0,100,(1000000))})

In [173]: %timeit df['clip_values'] = df['values'].map(lambda x : 20 if x > 20 else x)
1 loop, best of 3: 193 ms per loop

In [174]: %timeit df['clip_values_v2'] = np.where(df['values'] > 20, 20, df['values'])
100 loops, best of 3: 6.12 ms per loop

In [175]: %timeit df['clip_values_v3'] = df['values'].values.clip(max=20)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.95 ms per loop
```